# how to design a power supply with a supercapacitor

Tags: power-supply, rectifier, supercapacitor

[image][image]I'm ask to design a power supply unit which could change its voltage from 0 V to
20 V DC and its current to 0 A to 5 A. The maximum internal resistance of the unit is 1 kΩ. At
the same time, it could also store energy on a double layer capacitor or what we call a
“supercapacitor”. Is the design possible? What is the maximum power the design could give?
If the supply is cut off what required size of the supercapacitor is needed so that the unit could
continue supply electrical energy for 3 minutes with a minimum functioning voltage of 20 V at
5 A. Draw the equivalent block and circuit diagram of the power supply unit.

ive made a diagram as asked. is it correct. is there anything else missing. what is the size of the supercapacitor to make it work when cut off for 3 minutes. please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry mate, 5 A at 20 V for 3 minutes requires a battery. It would be a 3000 F 40 V capacitor, which might cost $1200, and be the size of a suitcase.

Comment: and a battery capable of that could be a stack of 10 cellphone batteries, the size of a cigarette box, $50 maybe. Both cases need some careful charge/discharge circuits, not just substituting them in for the smoothing capacitor.

Comment: And please explain why you have that collection of meters and resistors.

Comment: can you give me a simple circuit diagram on how you understand this design problem for clarification purposes. please

Comment: @tomnexus: I think you slipped a decimal place on your capacitor calculation. Assuming that an ultracapacitor can be charged to 2.5V and can be used down to 1.0V, I calculate that 7000F would deliver the 18kJ required. 3000F @ 40V would hold more than 10x the energy, 240kJ.

Comment: can you give me a diagram on how you understand this problem. please i just need it

Comment: @DaveTweed ah, yes. Too quick with mental arithmetic. I started off with 5 A x 200 s, and then rounded up a lot for a small depth of discharge. So it could be done with say 3x3000F, $200.

Comment: how about the circuit diagram. thank you very much for the help

Comment: bro, its supercapacitor to be used. not ultra.

Comment: in the picture aboove, is the design acceptable? this time, i'd put a supercap and a load.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "simple" answer to this problem. The block diagram would look something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP7RQB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: this is really great. but i think its supercapacitor to be used not ultra. can you give me also the equivalent circuit diagram of the problem? thank you

Comment: Look, we're not going to do your homework for you. This was intended as a hint to get you started in the correct direction. It's up to you to fill in the details, including the specifications of your supercapacitor.

Comment: oh im sorry for that. just having a lack of time. our submission will be tomorrow. one more, can i have a circuit diagram equivalent?

Comment: Please, I only need the circuit diagram . thats all. please

Comment: I really beg your pardon sir..

Comment: sir. the circuit diagram. just the same on how you do to your block diagram.

Comment: Dude. Do your own homework. When you have a job, are you going to go around begging other people to do your work for you?

Comment: okay. i understand.referring to the what tomnexus have said, where can i put the supercap as well as the battery ?